# VSTS - How to add Bug using Scrum template - No dropdown

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services, with the Scrum template. I can't figure out how to add a bug. I HAVE selected the option to treat bugs as backlog items. However, when I go to add a new backlog item, there is no dropdown for the Type (see below screenshot):

[image]

All the examples that I've seen online for adding a bug show a dropdown for "Type", where you can choose "Bug", but for me, there is no dropdown.

Note that if I add it as a regular Product Backlog Item, I can then edit it and change the type to "Bug", but that is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure [Bugs as Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog). This has to be done at the individual Team level.